# Precalc, Evaluating Limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Maybe I'm just having a dumb moment, but can someone please explain to  me why $$\underset{x \unicode{x2192} 2a}{\,\mathrm{lim}\,}\displaystyle{\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{6}{x}} - \displaystyle{\frac{6}{a}}}{x - a}}  =  \underset{x \unicode{x2192} 2a}{\,\mathrm{lim}\,}\displaystyle{\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{6 \left( a - x \right) }{ax}}}{x - a}}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make common denominator in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way how you add or subtract fractions with different denominators:

$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$

You can't add or subtract fractions with different denominators, so you multiply something into one fraction to make the denominator similar to another fraction.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d} & = \frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{d}{d}\right) - \frac{c}{d}\left(\frac{b}{b}\right) \\
& = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}; \, a=c \\
& = \frac{ad-ba}{bd}; \\
& = \frac{a(d-b)}{bd}; \\
\end{align}$$

In this case we multiplied $\frac{d}{d}$ into the first fraction and $\frac{b}{b}$ into the second fraction so that they will have a common denominator of $\frac{1}{bd}$.

One example would be if you have $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} & = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2^2} \\
& = \frac{2}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \\
& = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}$$